# Custom Themes for Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, ui, themes

For older Mac OS Versions like 10.4 or sometimes 10.5 you can find lots of themes, which change the whole UI.
Now my problem is that I'm using Mac OS Lion (10.7.3) and I want to change the UI, because I don't like the current one very much. I looked around in the web, but I couldn't find anything.
So is it really like that, that there isn't any other, alternative UI for Mac OS Lion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [Crystal Black](http://www.marsthemes.com/crystalblack/), which seems to be the only theme for OS X Lion that's available.
[image: Crystal Black: theme for OS X Lion]
It is *not* free, and costs $8.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that is really the only theme for Mac OS Lion yet... I still hope that some other themes come in the next time...